# compressing file to gz

Tags: java, compression, gzip

Exist some other way in order to compress to gz better?

```
FileOutputStream outFile = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
GZIPOutputStream out = new GZIPOutputStream(outFile);
byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
int len;
while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) 
{
    out.write(buf, 0, len);
}
in.close();
out.close();
outFile.close();
```

Comment: What do you mean by "better"? There are issues in terms of you not closing streams if an exception is thrown, and I'd probably use a larger buffer... but we don't really know what you're trying to improve.

Comment: Define better. Do you want it to be faster? Do you want your Java code to be less lines of code?

Comment: [GZIPOutputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/zip/GZIPOutputStream.html) is given by Java itself and hence it is definitely the recommended way to compress in gz format

Comment: Is possible do not use the loop while?

Comment: @Jjreina Do not increase the byte array size and remove the while.., that will be simply wastage of memory. while loop optimizes it for smaller files.

Comment: @Jjreina - your current writes are not buffered, which will often slow down the write process. Try using a buffered output stream (in between the GZipOutputStream and FileOutputStream).